# UserControl throwing exception "Cross-thread operation not valid"

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a usercontrol and two classes I want to print result of my class1 into usercontrol.I am sending result from class using this line

```
((merge.MyControl)(MyControlInstance)).CLIDisplay = e.WorkItem.CustomerId;
```

my control property to show result is

```
public string CLIDisplay
        {
            get { return lblResultCLI.Text; }
            set
            {
                    lblResultCLI.Text = value;

            }
        }
```

but I am getting following Exception when i called a class to my c# form

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'tbxEvents' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

Comment: You haven't explained what you're doing in terms of threading, which is obviously important. What research have you done around this error?

Comment: The error is about `tbxEvents` which is kind of missing in the code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to use invoke

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
{
   lblResultCLI.Text = value;
});
```

Next time make sure you use google...

[Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

This error occurs because lblResultCLI was created on another thread than the one you're running your code on, that is why you will have to use Invoke , so that the code accessing the lblResultCLI control executes on the same thread as it was created on.

Comment: To be honest, this is a poor answer - you have done nothing to explain **why** the OP needs to use Invoke.

Comment: This is a duplicate, why should I bother? I posted a link to a similar question with some good explanations

Comment: thanks its worked ...I have researched before asking question  but did't get my problem solved..

Comment: @anima - that is good - you provided some context to your answer. *Why should you bother?* If you want people to up vote you, you should give informative answers, rather than just little more than a line of code.